# JavaScript code not working, im not sure why

Tags: javascript, html

Heres the HTML:

```
<!doctype html>
<head>
  <title>Food Saver</title>
<script src="mycode.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <form>
    <input  type="text" id="foodInput" placeholder="Enter food">
    <input  type="button" id="addFood" value="Add Food">
  </form>
  <ul id="foodList">
  </ul>
</body>
</html>
```

and heres the JavaScript linked to it:

```
window.onload=init;
function init(){
  var addFoodButton = getElementById("addFood");
  addFoodButton.onclick = handleAddFoodButtonClick;
}
function handleAddFoodButtonClick(){
   var textInput=getElementById("foodInput");
   var food = textInput.value;

  if(food===""){
    alert("Please enter a food");
  }
  else{
    var li = document.createElement("li");
    li.innerHTML=food;
    var ul = getElementById("foodList");
    ul.appendChild(li);
  }
}
```

Why when I try and submit a food value or an empty string nothing happens, what is the error in my code

Comment: Where is `getElementById` defined? or did you miss `document.`

Comment: Read the error console. That will throw a ReferenceError, if nothing else.

Comment: Hate to be that guy but you should use jQuery.

Comment: Check out http://www.creativebloq.com/javascript/javascript-debugging-beginners-3122820 debugging javascript is a valuble asset to have when using the languange in any situation.

Comment: @shriek: Why? What frightens you about this simple code?

Comment: @cookiemonster Apart from him missing document on all element selectors? Nothing, really. It's just concise and less error prone.

Comment: @shriek: Plenty of people make simple mistakes while using jQuery too, which is why there are hundreds of thousands of jQuery questions on SO.

Comment: and @shriek im pretty new to javascript i started reading a book on it a few weeks ago and im not really sure what jQuery is, ive heard of it lots of times, is it a javascript library?

Comment: Can't say I agree, @shriek. jQuery is just a library for javascript and it's interaction with the browser DOM. Javascript is a language utilized in many different applications, and things like Node.js are becoming more and more popular. Thus knowing Javascript is a significant asset to have if you're moving into web development.

Not to mention, libraries come and go, whereas programming languages tend to have more longevity (relatively speaking).

Answer (score 3):

getElementById should be document.getElementById:

```
window.onload=init;
function init(){
  var addFoodButton = document.getElementById("addFood");
  addFoodButton.onclick = handleAddFoodButtonClick;
}
function handleAddFoodButtonClick(){
   var textInput = document.getElementById("foodInput");
   var food = textInput.value;

  if(food===""){
    alert("Please enter a food");
  }
  else{
    var li = document.createElement("li");
    li.innerHTML=food;
    var ul = document.getElementById("foodList");
    ul.appendChild(li);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
window.onload=init;
function init(){
  var addFoodButton = document.getElementById("addFood");
  addFoodButton.onclick = handleAddFoodButtonClick;
}
function handleAddFoodButtonClick(){
   var textInput=getElementById("foodInput");
   var food = textInput.value;

  if(food===""){
    alert("Please enter a food");
  }
  else{
    var li = document.createElement("li");
    li.innerHTML=food;
    var ul = document.getElementById("foodList");
    ul.appendChild(li);
  }
}
```

Comment: It is incorrect in at least two other places as well. Make sure to also provide instructions for how to troubleshoot this sort of issue.

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you're not seeing what's wrong, it's a good idea to throw your code into [JSLint](http://www.jslint.com/), keep hitting the JSLint button until it's not giving you any errors (or you decide to ignore or disable some warnings).

It can teach you a lot in no time. I just did that and came up with JSLint's suggestions.

```
function handleAddFoodButtonClick() {
    'use strict';

    var food = document.getElementById('foodInput').value;

    // if variable is false, zero, null, undefined, empty string or NaN, it's false
    if (!food) {
        alert('Please enter a food');
    } else {
        var li = document.createElement('li');
        li.innerHTML = food;
        document.getElementById('foodList').appendChild(li);
    }
}

function init() {
    'use strict';
    var addFoodButton = document.getElementById('addFood');
    addFoodButton.onclick = handleAddFoodButtonClick;
}

window.onload = init;
```

You could also paste your code to [JSHint](http://www.jshint.com/), in fact, with your original code it gave 3 errors:

```
One undefined variable
3   getElementById
7   getElementById
16  getElementById
```